# convert string that contains <,> (Special chars) to html

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, browser, replace

I have a string that is, `<some text>`
I'm trying to highlight the "te" in it, using replace function

```
 InnerHTML = innerHTML.replace(some_Regex_Pattern['te'], '<span style=\'background-color:#FFFB00\'>$&</span>');
```

The string I obtain is,

```
<some <span class=\'highlight\' style=\'background-color:#FFFB00\'>te</span>xt>
```

Now setting this to element.innerHTML,  is considered as an HTML tag, causing problem.
In DOM I get the element as

```
<some <span class=\'highlight\' style=\'background-color:#FFFB00\'>te</span>xt></some>
```

I get the string in malformed form, how can I convert it to correct format, without making changes to the correct html tag i.e  here?

How can I solve this issue,.. If it is not understandable, please comment,..

Comment: the string that you obtained is not valid html, it is malformed. Starting with < and then ending with > .... ???

Comment: Yes, exactly,.. I get the string in malformed form, how can I convert it to correct format, without making changes to the correct html tag i.e <span> here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;` before replacing the `te`.

```
innerHTML.replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;')...
```

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expressions and HTML don't mix very well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).  In your case, if you're *very careful* you can manually escape all the proper values and produce valid HTML.  If you're *even a little careless* you will have problems with malformed or unsafe content.  This is not to say "you absolutely must never do it that way", but you should at least be aware of the pitfalls involved in doing so.

The recommended solution is never to programmatically manipulate HTML strings yourself.  Instead, you should manipulate [`HTMLElement` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) and trust your JavaScript engine to handle the HTML.

In your case, I'd say there are two components to the question.

One: convert a string into a representation where pieces of the string are marked as "should-be-highlighted" or "should-not-be-highlighted".  If you introduce the following interface (you used the TypeScript tag after all):

```
interface HighlightableString {
    value: string;
    highlighted: boolean;
}
```

Then a string with highlighted sections could be represented as `Array<HighlightableString>`.

So you need a function to convert a string like `"<some text>"` and the substring `"te"` to something like

```
[ 
  {value: "<some ", highlighted: false}, 
  {value: "te", highlighted: true}, 
  {value: "xt>", highlighted: false}
]
```

Here's one possible implementation of that function, but you can do it any way you want.  And this is a perfectly valid place to use regular expressions, since there is no way to represent "unsafe" or "malformed" HTML here:

```
function highlightSubstring(s: string, substring: string): Array<HighlightableString> {
    if (substring.length === 0) return [{ value: s, highlighted: false }]
    const ret: Array<HighlightableString> = [];
    for (
      var prevPos = 0, pos = s.indexOf(substring); 
      pos >= 0; 
      prevPos = pos + substring.length, pos = s.indexOf(substring, prevPos)
    ) {
        ret.push({ value: s.substring(prevPos, pos), highlighted: false });
        ret.push({ value: substring, highlighted: true });
    }
    ret.push({ value: s.substring(prevPos), highlighted: false });
    return ret;
}
```

Two: given an `Array<HighlightableString>`, a parent `HTMLElement`, and some way of highlighting text (e.g., an `HTMLElement` representing such highlighting), add the properly highlighted text to that parent element.  This is where you really don't want to be using regular expressions, or HTML text at all.  Here is one possible implementation:

```
function appendHighlightedString(
  highlightableStrings: Array<HighlightableString>, 
  parentElement: HTMLElement, 
  highlightElement: HTMLElement
) {
  highlightableStrings.forEach(hs => {
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(hs.value);
      if (hs.highlighted) {
          const highlightClone = highlightElement.cloneNode(true);
          highlightClone.appendChild(textNode)
          parentElement.appendChild(highlightClone)
      } else {
          parentElement.appendChild(textNode);
      }
  })
}
```

Notice how that function is using [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) nodes and element cloning and appending.  It never looks at HTML directly.

Okay, let's see if it works.  I will try it with the content `<test content>`:

```
// make a highlight element
const highlightElement = document.createElement("span");
highlightElement.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFB00';

const wholeString = document.createElement("div"); // or whatever the parent element is
appendHighlightedString(
  highlightSubstring("<test content>", "te"), 
  wholeString, 
  highlightElement
);
```

Let's see what it did in Firefox:

```
console.log(wholeString.innerHTML);
// &lt;<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 251, 0);">te</span>st 
// con<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 251, 0);">te</span>nt&gt;
```

Well, the browser decided to use `rgb(255, 251, 0)` instead of `#FFFB00`.  But that's the browser's prerogative; we are out of the HTML game.  The point is if you add that element to your document,

```
document.body.appendChild(wholeString);
```

it will be highlighted the way you want.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!